# Theme install failed in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I just tried to install a theme from  http://webdesignandsuch.com/fancymoves-jquery-product-slider-2/ Which name is "FancyMoves a jQuery Product Slider", but wordpress write me: “The package could not be installed. The theme is missing the style.css stylesheet.” How can i solve?

Answer (score 2):

That's because what you are trying to install isn't a Wordpress theme, it's a jQuery slider. To be honest I think you've got quite a lot of learning ahead of you, start by using plugins available in the Wordpress repo and then build up to incorporating custom jQuery into your theme.

Answer (score 2):

"FancyMoves a jQuery Product Slider" is not a theme! Its just a jQuery product slider.

Check the [WordPress theme section](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/) for basic free themes.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem can occur if you're trying to upload a theme file from admin panel, which is zipped in `.rar` format. Wordpress doesn't seem to perform so well with .rar format.

I have experienced this, so thought it would be worth sharing.